# Java : Hang when socket used second time

Tags: java, sockets, stream

I have a client class and a server class. There is a client method which I use to call the server and my code hangs if I try use this method more than once during a jvm session.

Client code's main method:

```
methodA();
methodA();
ois.close(); //ObjectInputStream
oos.close(); //ObjrctOutputStream
is.close(); //InputStream
os.close(); //OutputStream
socket.close();
```

Client code's `methodA()` looks like this:

```
os = socket.getOutputStream();
oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
oos.writeObject(obj);
is = socket.getInputStream();
ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
Object o = ois.readObject();
```

Server code's main method looks like:

```
while (true) {
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
    is = socket.getInputStream();
    ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
    Object o = ois.readObject();
    servermethod();
}
oos.close();
ois.close();
is.close();
os.close();
serverSocket.close();
```

The server's `serverMethod()` looks like:

```
os = socket.getOutputStream();
oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
Object ob = getObject() ; //this method is working fine
oos.writeObject(ob);
```

What I wanted to do was to have the client call the server a few times using `methodA()`. I might not be handling the streams correctly. Any help?

Comment: Are you ever flushing any output streams?

Comment: No, i'm not flushing the output streams.

Comment: You say that `oos`, etc are initialized in `methodA` but they are closed outside of `methodA`.  Thus `oos.close()` only happens to the last value of `oos`.

Comment: What does `servermethod()` do?  Unless it writes an object back to the client, of course the client will hang because nothing is sending it objects.

Comment: Yes, servermethod() is sending back objects. Does oos.close() need to be inside methodA() ? I had declared oos, ois, is, os, as static class variables so i could use them for other methods too.

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the servermethod() code as well.

Comment: Hi Sajith, i just posted the servermethod()

Comment: Is it even possible to have a client which does a writeObject(), the server does readObject(), then the server does a writeObject() in reply, and the client does a readObject(), that would be a full cycle. And then i want to repeat the cycle, by calling the client method again.

Comment: i'm not too sure about when/where to create/close the socket connection, and the stream connections.

Comment: Your server code doesn't expect for the socket to be reused, hence calling multiple times from client using the same socket won't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are definitely a few things wrong with this code:

- You are creating ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream repeatedly on top of the same streams.  This is not how how they are supposed to be used.  What you are supposed to do is create the ObjectXxxStream once, and then call readObject or writeObject multiple times on the same ObjectXxxStream.  If you are sending the same object multiple times, you need to call `reset` before writing the object again.
- You are not flushing the streams.  If you don't flush after writing, there is no guarantee that the serialized representation will get sent to the other end ... where something is waiting for the bytes to arrive.

Answer (score 0):

Your server end code is written in a way to read only one object and write only one object to a newly created `Socket`. Hence you try to reuse the `Socket` a second or nth time, it doesn't get back a response from the server. There are 2 ways to fix it.

1. You can fix on the server end : This will be an elaborate change, but better use of resources. You don't stop reading the stream until it is closed.
2. You fix it in the client end : Instead of creating the `Socket` outside the `main` method, you create the `Socket` inside `MethodA()`. Easy and dirty solution though.